# using tcpdf split a pdf into two parts

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, tcpdf

Any solution need to split pdf  into two parts using php code,any sample or library links

https://gist.github.com/maccath/3981205 i alredy tried this and got an error as FPDF error: File is encrypted!

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $pagecount; $i++) {
    $new_pdf = new FPDI();
    $new_pdf->AddPage();
    $new_pdf->setSourceFile($filename);
    $new_pdf->useTemplate($new_pdf->importPage($i));
try {
        $new_filename = $end_directory.str_replace('.pdf', '', $filename).'_'.$i.".pdf";
        $new_pdf->Output($new_filename, "F");
        echo "Page ".$i." split into ".$new_filename."<br />\n";
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    }
}
```

}

and now am trying http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Setasign](http://www.setasign.com/support/faq/fpdi/can-fpdi-import-encrypted-pdf-documents/#question-205) site FPDI will not import encrypted or protected PDFs, so you need to check the properties of the PDF you're working with to see whether this is the case. It's possible that there might be a way to work-around the issue of protected PDFs, but if there is no encryption/decryption support in the FPDI class then it will not be possible to work with the PDF as-is.